# How do I display Google Analytics reports or realtime report on my website page?

Tags: php, google-analytics

is that possible to display google analytics reports or realtime report on my website page?

1. i have created google analytics api and tested on the localhost and it is working and redirect url which i given into google analytics api `Redirect URIs:`
2. After all the process of `google analytics api` how do i display analytics
   visitor reports on my website page?
3. How to display google analytics realtime report on my website page?
4. i want to display `Analytics Standard Reports` Like `(Real-Time-Overview,Audience- Overview,Traffic-Sources-Overview,Content-Overview,Conversions-Overview)` Reports Or Chart On My Website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real time visitors from Google Analytics. How to get it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839430/real-time-visitors-from-google-analytics-how-to-get-it)

Answer (score 3):

The real-time reports are not yet possible. If you take a look at:
https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list

On the top of the list is "Access to Real Time data".

Answer (score 3):

Check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/embeddedanalytics-realtime-reporting.html).

This is a service which allows developers to easily embed GA based charts directly into websites.  There is no need to know the API or any other charting software.  All you do is create a chart on our site, grab a snippet of code, and embed on your site where you want the chart to show.

*(disclaimer - I work with them)*

Comment: hi, is it possible to embed current real time users fetched through google analytics api (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get) by EmbeddedAnalytics?

Comment: Yes - we support Realtime Reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Google has now launched a real time API. It is only in beta, however, you can sign up now, and it should be available to everyone later.

http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/google-analytics-launches-real-time-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Google has launched the real-time API, To embed, Follow the steps, embed the code and have fun .
Here is the examples.

[https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/](http://Google%20real-time%20API%20examples)

Answer (score -1):

You can use following API provided by Google.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/