# Google Analytics - Custom Alerts for Real-Time data

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking to create a custom alert to notify me whenever X number of people are on the site at once. This data is already available using the Real-Time reports page. However, this does not seem possible via the Intelligence Events section. From there, I'm only able to create custom alerts based off Day, Week, or Month data. Has anybody found another area of Google Analytics that would make this type of report possible?

Comment: You're correct, real time alerts just aren't in the feature set of GA right now, nor is real time data available through the API. There's some info out there about scraping real time data, though (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021554/scraping-real-time-visitors-from-google-analytics), so you might be able to build a tool that scrapes the real time data every X minutes and emails you based on that.

Answer (score 5):

Google Analytics have just launched a Beta of their Real Time API which might let you do this: http://techcrunch.com/2013/08/01/google-launches-real-time-api-for-analytics-in-invite-only-beta/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the real-time API for that. It's been possible for quite a few years now. You can find all the [documentation for that right here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/). It's typical OAuth + JSON API.

You can also use a paid service. I built one, [Metrics Watch](https://metricswatch.com/real-time-alerts-for-google-analytics/). It really depends of your goal and how critical this is to your business/job. If it's critical, I would highly encourage you to look for a paid service, no matter which one.

Hope that helps!