# Browser and devices data from Google analytics code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is is possible to leverage Google analytics code to get browser and devices data. Want to add this data to anonymous feedback widget.

We already use classic GA tracking so thought it might be an option to reuse whatever method they use for recording browser, os, device etc that's available in GA reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically every browser is a code that is scraping data from a website. If it can, you can too.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/

[Scraping Real Time Visitors from Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021554/scraping-real-time-visitors-from-google-analytics)

I recommend you use Google Analytics APIs for this purpose.

These are a few links that can help you.