# Pageviews Per minute data

Tags: api, google-analytics, real-time, pageviews

I have read the documentation for both core and real time API and I was unable to find whether it's possible to get values of "Pageviews Per minute" as shown in the left graph:

[image: Graph from Google Analytics]

Is there any way to get the minute data via the API or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't get this metric via API and the only way would be to create a scraper for getting the data from the web UI. Take a look here [Scraping Real Time Visitors from Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021554/scraping-real-time-visitors-from-google-analytics/18945515)